# When something entered into input do something with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi thanks for reading.

I have a input box which is for urls to be given. When an user enters a url the user has to click on a button to get values from it.

which is this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".button-class").click( function(event) {
   //do something
 )};
)};
```

Eventually all users click on the button. What I want to do is as soon as they entered the url or something the script should be triggered.

is there anything like that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(".button-class").entered( function(event) {
   //do something
 )};
)};
```

thanks.

Comment: check [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for a change event:

```
$( "input[type='text']" ).change(function() {
  // Check input( $( this ).val() ) for validity here
});
```

Another options are [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) functions.